# Getting echo within echo to work together

Tags: php

In a little trouble with this, is they any way i can get to echo's working together see code below,

```
<?php $youtube_vimeo_player = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_youtube_vimeo_player',TRUE); ?>

<?php echo $video->embed(' <?php echo $youtube_vimeo_player['url']; ?> ', '', ''); ?>
```

I'm wanting the info brought from the vimeo_player url to be entered into the video->embed section.
Any help on this would much be appreciated : )

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that simply `<?php echo $video->embed($youtube_vimeo_player['url'], '', ''); ?>` won't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo $video->embed("'".$youtube_vimeo_player['url']."'", '', ''); ?>
```

Comment: I would click the tick but I'm not allowed : ) do you know of a way I can make it so if no youtube video show vimeo video and if no vimeo show error message ? here is my coding <?php $youtube_vimeo_player = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_youtube_vimeo_player',TRUE); ?>
  <?php echo $video->embed("'".$youtube_vimeo_player['youtubeurl']."'", '', ''); ?>
  <?php echo $video->embed("'".$youtube_vimeo_player['vimeourl']."'", '', ''); ?>

Answer (score 2):

try it like this:

```
<?php $youtube_vimeo_player = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_youtube_vimeo_player',TRUE); ?>

<?php echo $video->embed( $youtube_vimeo_player['url'], '', ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
' <?php echo $youtube_vimeo_player['url']; ?> '
```

with

```
"{$youtube_vimeo_player['url']}"
```

You dont need echoing *inside* the php string. Note that `{` and `}` are the special way to embed array index, or object method call into the string, they are not present in final string.

Btw, it's sufficient to just do

```
echo $video->embed($youtube_vimeo_player['url'], '', '');
```

As `$youtube_vimeo_player['url']` already shoud be the string

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't that crazy, but thanks for remembering us it could seem to.

Thou shall write:

```
<?php
  $youtube_vimeo_player = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_youtube_vimeo_player',TRUE);
  $url=$youtube_vimeo_player['url'];
  $video->embed($url, '', '');
?>
```

Educate yourself on the concept of *variable*, and remember, php has only *one level of embedding* (that is one level of `<?php ... ?>` — no nesting)

And believe it, it's better this way.